# Symfony2: Form Collection of entities with one-to-one relationship

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have 2 entities:

1. **TransactionDefaultParametersEntity**

   - Parameter: widgetType
   - Parameter: defaultParameters (Has one to one relationship with DefaultParametersEntity)
2. **DefaultParametersEntity**

   - Parameter: checkIn
   - Parameter: checkOut
   - Parameter: currency
   - Parameter: adults

The controller provides a collection of TransactionDefaultParametersEntities, and for each I want a *form* displayed with all DefaultParameterEntity parameters as well as the widgetType parameter provided by the  TransactionDefaultParametersEntity.

Currently I have a form type for each entity:

1. **TransactionDefaultParametersFormType**

   ```
   class DefaultSettingsFormType extends AbstractType
   {

   /**
    * @param  FormBuilderInterface $builder
    * @param  array                $options
    */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       $builder
           ->add('defaultParameters', 'collection', ['type' => default_parameters', 'allow_add' => true]);
   }

   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
      {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' =>    'AppBundle\Entity\TransactionDefaultParametersEntity',
           'create' => false
          ));
      }

      public function getName()
      {
       return 'transaction_default_parameters';
      }
   }
   ```
2. **DefaultParametersFormType**

   ```
   class DefaultParametersFormType extends AbstractType
   {
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
     {
       $builder
           ->add('widgetType', 'choice', [
               'choices' => [
                   'Default',
                   'Booking Engine',
                   'Informative'
               ],
               'label' => 'Widget Type'
           ])
           ->add('checkIn', 'text', ['label' => 'Check In'])
           ->add('checkOut', 'text', ['label' => 'Check Out'])
           ->add('currency', 'text', ['label' => 'Currency'])
           ->add('adults', 'text', ['label' => 'adults']);
     }

     public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
     {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\DefaultParametersEntity',
       ));
     }

     public function getName()
     {
       return 'default_parameters';
     }
   }
   ```

And lastly in the controller:

```
    // $transactionDefaultParametersCollection is a collection of TransactionDefaultParameterEntities
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($transactionDefaultParametersCollection)
                    ->add('transactionDefaultParameters', 'transaction_default_settings')
                    ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'))
                    ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // do something
    }

    return $this->render(
        'settings/editDefaults.html.twig',
        [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]
    );
```

If this wasn't clear please let me know :). Also if I could be pointed to an article that would be very helpful. I looked at how to embed a collection of forms but this was a different case than the example provided.